# Hide Android keyboard on orientation change

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have used following code to display keyboard.On orientation change keyboard is not dismissing so to dismiss the keyboard I have used hideSoftInputFromWindow method but it is not working. I have tried all the solutions found.But no one is working.I have added the codes used for showing and hiding keyboards. Please help me.Thanks in advance

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);;
                        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
                                InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
                        imm.showSoftInput(_searchView,
                                InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

to hide Keyboard

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(_searchView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the solution is in the manifest file in this line android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize"

"stateUnchanged" will make the state of keyboard same as it was in earlier state. Either hidden or visible.

"adjustResize" will make your edit text visible.

Example:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize" >
```

Comment: You can try also with "stateHidden|adjustPan" it will hide the keyboard when the activity is launched

Answer (score 3):

inside onCreate:

```
Window window = getWindow();
if (window != null) {
    window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  //hide keyboard
}
```

Comment: try to use getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

Comment: I can't use getWindow().setSoftInputMode( WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN); because I have to use getWindow().setSoftInputMode( WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

Answer (score 0):

In manifest.xml file apply following attribute in your activity tag

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

This method is called when screen rotated

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration myConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(myConfig);
int orient = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation; 
switch(orient) {
            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

            //hide keyboard or whatever you want

                break;
            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

            //hide keyboard or whatever you want
                break;
            default:
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
                //hide keyboard or whatever you want

                break;
            }
}
```

In your Manifest, put:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:configChanges="orientation">
```